# Stop Spell check in taxonomy field

Tags: publishing-page, taxonomy, spellchecker

I have taxonomy controls on my page-layout which I want to stop spell check at the time of check in page.

The issue I'm facing is that I have 2 taxonomy field on page which behaves differently. In one taxonomy the spell check in not working and in another one spell checking is working.

when I check in the page there is message in pop up that

> 1 spelling error(s) found

This error is because of one taxonomy only. If I will remove that field than it will not give spell error.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery and CSS to disable spell check in fields present on your publishing page.
Check the articles:

http://robertocina.wordpress.com/2014/09/25/disable-spell-checking-on-a-publishing-page-in-sharepoint-2013/

http://www.restfuldevelopment.net/sharepoint-2010-fix-for-spell-check-of-publishing-site-userfield-using-jquery/